How do I add a column to all tables?
I am trying to add a column called UpdateT2 to all the tables (without knowing their names) in my database.
I am running the following script:
SET @DatabaseName = "intermedia";
SET @ColumnName= " UpdateT2 TIMESTAMP";

Select Concat ('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, 
          ' Add' , @ColumnName, 
          ' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;') as QUERY
From information_schema.tables
where table_schema = @DatabaseName;

The script runs correctly, that is, it does not give any errors, but the column is not added to the tables.
Instead, if I run a: ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UpdateT2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; It works perfectly and adds the column to the table.
Why in the first case it doesn't work? What is the difference?

The published statement produces a bunch of alter statements - you need to execute them to complete the task.

But with that script I should import the column in all the tables, right?

Not with you, a select statement is just that, it doesn't execute an alter statement. https://dbfiddle.uk/WQigaJFV

And what other option is there to modify all the tables at the same time?

You might consider https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html but it's a bit more work than copy,paste and execute and can only execute one statement at a time.

You need to loop over a cursor for a query that selects all table names. In the loop you prepare and execute an ALTER query for that table.
